# Using TDE on MySQL in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: mysql, encryption, database-security, tde

I was looking around for some solution to bring TDE to MySQL. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570457/how-can-i-use-transparent-data-encryption-with-mysql) asked in here before.

But the question seems to be about enabling a TDE solution to a MySQL database that is installed in a Linux environment.

In my case, I would need a TDE solution for MySQL that is installed in a Windows Server 2008 R2 environment.

I have found [NetLib](http://www.netlib.com/mysql-encryption.asp) and it seems to be working for me. Question is, are there any other alternatives? Also, is NetLib good?

EDIT:

So now using TrueCrypt with MySQL is possible. But, is there any other alternative to this? One that has been audited perhaps?

Comment: If NetLib Encryptionizer is working for you may I ask why you are still looking?  Are you running into any problems?  If so, please submit a support request at [www.netlib.com/support/](http://www.netlib.com/support/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't care what solution you're using as long as you provide it a filesystem that acts like a filesystem. It deals only at the file level. Do understand that performance may be **severely** impacted, however.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I want to implement this on a MySQL that installed on a Windows environment is to make MySQL point to a Linux machine with eCryptfs in it?

Comment: What? No. eCryptfs encrypts the filesystem on Linux. There are plenty of transparent full disk encryption solutions for Windows, such as TrueCrypt. Get one of those working in a way you're happy with, then install MySQL as normal and configure it to use that filesystem. See https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+disk+encryption